# Does Scala's BigDecimal violate the equals/hashCode contract?

Tags: scala, equals, hashcode, bigdecimal

As the `Ordered` `trait` demands, the `equals` method on Scala's `BigDecimal` class is consistent with the ordering. However, the hashcode is simply taken from the wrapped `java.math.BigDecimal` and is therefore inconsistent with equals.

```
object DecTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val d1 = BigDecimal("2")
    val d2 = BigDecimal("2.00")
    println(d1 == d2) //prints true
    println(d1.hashCode == d2.hashCode) //prints false
  }
}
```

I can't find any reference to this being a known issue. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The people over on the Scala User mailing list seem to agree that this is a bug. I guess it's not been picked up until now because no-one has ever used a `BigDecimal` as a key in a hash structure. It's been [filed as bug #2304](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2304)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** This answer is wrong! I've left it up because I think the comments are useful in seeing why it's wrong.

---

This isn't an example of a violation of the `equals`/`hashCode` contract. You would need to check whether `d1.equals(d2)` is equal to prove that. And indeed, `d1.equals(d2)` returns false. Why?

It's because "2" isn't precisely the same thing as "2.00"; the value on the right has more significant digits. In other words, they are equal in *value* (2 == 2.00), but differ in *scale* (0 != 2).

If you read the source code [here](http://scala-tools.org/scaladocs/scala-library/2.7.1/BigDecimal.scala.html#Some%28107%29), you can see that for two numbers, it falls through to the Java `BigDecimal` `equals` implementation. Then, reading the [**Java documentation**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) describes how this works in greater detail.

Comment: Whoever is upvoting this needs to go and read about Scala! `==` in Scala is equivalent to `.equals` in Java. **This answer is wrong**

Comment: *@John* - have you tried running your answer in Scala? It is not correct! `scala.BigDecimal` and `java.math.BigDecimal` are different things

Comment: *@John* - sorry to carp on: if you follow your link, you can see that the `equals`  method falls through to Java's `BigDecimal.compare` method

Comment: @oxbow_lakes » Whoops, you're right. I actually made two mistakes, since I somehow ran this in Groovy (where it works) instead of in Scala. That'll teach me to answer without sufficient caffeine. Also, I think you meant compareTo, right?